# Convert git full clone to shallow clone

Tags: git

I was cloned a repo, and its size increases day by day. So I want to remove old commits and only keep the latest commit just like I'm re-cloning it with `--depth 1`. And I don't want to re-clone it, is there a way to convert the local repo to a shallow one and keep `git pull` working?

Comment: why don't you just clone locally however you want i.e. `cd /tmp/; git clone /my/fat/repo/.git --depth 1; ` - and then just move/rename/delete the directories as you see fit?

Comment: you will also have to set up remote correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can make a local copy of repository with using parameter "depth 1".
Just use local folder as a source for cloning.

For example:

```
git clone --depth 1 file://__absolute path__/localrepo localrepo.shallow
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand in the question, you would like to preserve only the current state of the working directory and remove the history. If that is the case, checkout the branch you would like to keep. Then remove all the git information there is. I generally use these commands running it from the working directory:

find . -type f | grep -i "\.git" | xargs rm

cd ..

git init

cd

git add --all

git commit -m "commit_message"

This would create a local copy containing only the current commit.

Comment: This will cause `git push` and `git push` fail to work

Comment: You need to add the remote to this.

git remote add <remote_name>. And then you can do the git push